# External Sharing Failed

Tags: error, external-sharing

[image]I have confirmed through the Admin menu for both SharePoint and OneDrive that sharing is enabled.  I've confirmed that the settings are congruent throughout both.  I have confirmed that sharing is enabled for the team site under site collections, although admittedly the sub-site that I'm trying to list is not listed, nor discoverable through Search from site collections.

Two errors are given from SharePoint:

> 1) Microsoft.SharePoint.InvitationUpdateException was thrown
>
> 2) Please contact IT department.  Correlation ID
>   e99a579e-b019-5000-5a22 ....